# relative clause or participle phrase

Tags: relative-clauses, participle-phrases

Today my English teacher(not a native) used the sentence below to introduce the idea of relative clause:

> People will buy the classics based on her recommendation but sales won't reach the kind of **numbers  achieved** in the first book club.

My teacher explained that the sentence above is a relative clause because **which were** is originally placed before **achieved** , and **numbers** is modified by "which were achieved in the first book club."

> People will People will buy the classics based on her recommendation but sales won't reach the kind of **numbers (which were) achieved** in the first book club.

My teacher said that **which were** is omitted in the sentence because grammar rule allows, and the omitted **which** represent **numbers**.  So, the relative clause part of the sentence can be seen as : Numbers were achieved in the first book club.

But my friend told me that the teacher is partly wrong because there is no such thing as omitting **which were** or that "**numbers which were achieved**" is transformed into "**numbers achieved**",
the term for this is called **participle phrase**. But my friend said that **relative clause** performs the same function as **participle phrase**, and the meaning does not differ, so the teacher isn't completely wrong.

So I am really confused because I was given two different thoughts,
at this point I don't know whom to trust, which one is right and which is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> People will buy the classics based on her recommendation but sales won't reach the kind of numbers (which is) **achieved in the first book club**.

It is perfectly reasonable to say that "which is" is omitted in the sentence.¹ Some linguists call this 'whiz-deletion' or 'relative-clause reduction'.

However, the modern reference grammar, *The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002) does not hold this view: they call it a **past-participial clause functioning as a post-head modifier**² in the NP structure. So, an NP can have any of these four types of clause as a post-head modifier:

> i. Where's **the book I lent you**? [relative] 
>   ii Kim is **the person to do the job**. [infinitival] 
>   iii **People living near the site** will be seriously disavantaged. [gerund-participial] 
>   iv She came across **some letters written by her grandmother**. [past-participial]

In short, neither your teacher nor your friend is wrong. These are two different analyses that will come up the same conclusion. Just like math: 3+3 equals 6, and so does 2+4 :).

---

¹ I find it more logical to say that the relativized element is "kind of number", which is singular. 
² Note that CGEL calls it a clause, not a phrase.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to make sure I am understanding the concept correctly, **People living near the site** can be rewritten to (relative clause) **People who live near the site** and **Some letters written by her grandmother** can be rewritten to **Some letters which were written by her grandmother**, and the meaning will remain the same, is this correct?

Comment: @HuanYing Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much again :)

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to have bothered you again , I came across this sentence in a journal "But even for these companies, **the social impact achieved**, much less the business benefit, is hard to determine." **achieved** would function as a past-participial modifying social impact, so can "which was " be understood to be between "**impact**" and "**achieved**" ?

Comment: @HuanYing Yes. The same applies here.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer :)

Comment: @HuanYing You're welcome. If you have anything else to ask you might need to create a chat room as the comment section is not for extended discussions. If it's not related to this topic (that is, a different question), just write a new post.

Answer (score 0):

> *People will buy the classics based on her recommendation but sales*
>   *won't reach the kind of numbers [achieved in the first book club]*.

The bracketed element does modify "kind of numbers", but it is a past-participial clause, not a relative one.

It has a similar meaning to the relative clause *which were achieved in the first book club*, but I'd avoid calling a relative clause since there is no possibility of it containing a relative phrase (cf. * *... but sales won't reach the kind of numbers which achieved in the first book club*).

Note that the crucial property of a relative clause is that it must contain an element - actually present or understood - that is anaphorically related to an antecedent. This is the basis for the term 'relative clause', and likewise relative pronoun.